# Make "save image as" link to a different image?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to protect images with a watermark, but I don't want to display the images on the website with the watermark. I created a php script that dynamically watermarks an image on the fly, but here's what I'd like to do with it:

I'd like for whenever someone right clicks and presses "save as" an image displayed on my website for it link to a different image that is watermarked. Is that possible? Should I go about this another way?

Any response in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Here's an example: http://fatpita.net/?i=14453 
When you save this image, the saved image is watermarked, but the website's image is not... I think they actually just mask the watermark on the website though.

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, the image in the example is already watermarked, but the watermark is positioned 'under' the background

Comment: I guess that's how i'll go about it then. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible in a safe way.

If the browser gets the unwatermarked file the user can save that file - maybe not using "save image as" but e.g. through Firefox's "page info  dialog which contains a full media list.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want unnecessary trouble for this task anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do anything that the user can't fake. The site you mentioned doesn't either - the watermark is always there.

Look at the actual source:

```
<div style="position:relative;width:768px;margin:9px auto 0;">
    <a href="http://fatpita.net/?i=4011" id="image">
        click on the image for another random funny picture<br>
        <img src="images/image (14453).jpg?4011">
    </a>
    <div id="jpgCover">
    </div>
</div>
```

They are actually covering over the watermark in HTML. It is still there, but there is a `div` in the way making sure you can't see it.

Remember the user can always remove this watermark by an easy crop.

Comment: When using "Save image", the browser is not typically making a new request. It just saves the image it already has into a file.